# Retrieving checkbox values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1"  class="trchoose">
<input type="checkbox" value="1"  class="trchoose">
<input type="checkbox" value="1"  class="trchoose">
<input type="checkbox" value="1"  class="trchoose">
```

​and following is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery('.trchoose').click(function() {
    alert('');
    res= jQuery(this).attr('class');
    alert(res);
});
```

Now I need to get value of the particular checkbox which was clicked. The above code of jQuery is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To get the value use `this.value` or `$(this).val()` plus you're missing `var`

Comment: Make sure you are using `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('.trchoose').click(function() {
    alert('');
    var res= this.value; // or jQuery(this).val() for jQuery version, but overhead.
    alert(res);
});
```

I assume that `res` is not a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1"  class="trchoose">
<input type="checkbox" value="2"  class="trchoose">
<input type="checkbox" value="3"  class="trchoose">
<input type="checkbox" value="4"  class="trchoose">​
```

Please check, your second checkbox is not closed!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('.trchoose').click(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });​
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/32VQ8/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.trchoose').click(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$('.trchoose').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
});​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/S4RVC/**

Comment: yes, either one works, but [`this.value` is 85% faster](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-plain-javascript/3)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jQuery('.trchoose').click(function() {
    alert('');
    var res= jQuery(this).val();
    alert(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function countChecked() {
  var n = $("input:checked").val();
     alert(n);
}
countChecked();
$(":checkbox").click(countChecked);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
jQuery('.trchoose').click(function() {
         alert(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkM8u/)

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML is being inserted into the DOM, you should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$('.trchoose').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```